# Kvm: 'kvmvapic.bin': No such file or directory

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization

I'm trying to set up virtual machines with kvm and spice. Every time I start a virtual machine it outputs an error and runs extremely slow.

```
max@TuxServer:~$ kvm-spice -hda vdisk.img -cdrom /media/Main/transfer/CDs/ubuntu-12.04-desktop-amd64.iso -boot d -m 1024 -vga cirrus -spice port=5900,addr=192.168.0.1,disable-ticketing
do_spice_init: starting 0.10.0
spice_server_add_interface: SPICE_INTERFACE_MIGRATION
spice_server_add_interface: SPICE_INTERFACE_KEYBOARD
spice_server_add_interface: SPICE_INTERFACE_MOUSE
Could not open option rom 'kvmvapic.bin': No such file or directory
spice_server_add_interface: SPICE_INTERFACE_QXL
red_worker_main: begin
ensure_display_channel_created: create display channel
ensure_cursor_channel_created: create cursor channel
```

The CPU has AMD-V. The OS is Ubuntu 12.04.1 x64 kernel 3.2.0-29

---------- edit -----------

kvm-ok prints:

```
INFO: /dev/kvm exists
KVM acceleration can be used
```

and apt-file search kvmvapic.bin outputs nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite not knowing what is the problem, i can give you some tips. First you can check if the problem is caused by that missing file. Using `apt-file` i get

```
$ apt-file search kvmvapic.bin
qemu-common: /usr/share/qemu/kvmvapic.bin
seabios: /usr/share/seabios/optionrom/kvmvapic.bin
```

So you should install `qemu-common` to get rid of that error.

Also you must check that your computer can run KVM with `kvm-ok` command:

```
$ kvm-ok
INFO: /dev/kvm exists
KVM acceleration can be used
```

As a last advice, despite using `kvm-spice` should enable by default KVM, you can try passing the flag `-enable-kvm`. Also you can redirect the logging to a file using `-D file.log` and try to find some info there.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for the good answer (sorry but I can't upvode) however non of them solve the problem.

Comment: I guess I was wrong in my comment. Adding -enable-kvm makes the virtual system run at fine speed even thought it still prints the error. So I guess I can ignore the error.

Comment: did you try installing `seabios` package?